# SIMPLE toggle image inquiry

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have 8 thumbnails, when the user hovers over any one of them, a separate div named 'target' displays an image.  By default 'target' is an empty div, until one of the thumbnails are hovered.

Question:
**How do I set 'target' to have a default image, without messing up the currently functionality of the hover?  I would like for that default image to be 'chart'**

```
<style>
#target { width: 1220px; height: 400px; }

.chart { background: url("theme/images/timeline.png") no-repeat 0 0; }

.html { background: url("theme/images/html_graph.png")  no-repeat 0 0; }
.oracle { background: url("theme/images/oracle_graph.png") no-repeat 0 0; }
.linux { background: url("theme/images/linux_graph.png") no-repeat 0 0; }
.php { background: url("theme/images/php_graph.png") no-repeat 0 0; }
.java { background: url("theme/images/java_graph.png") no-repeat 0 0; }
.prod { background: url("theme/images/prod_graph.png") no-repeat 0 0; }
.design { background: url("theme/images/design_graph.png") no-repeat 0 0; }
.pm { background: url("theme/images/pm_graph.png") no-repeat 0 0; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript/1.2">
function change(v) {
    var target = document.getElementById("target");
    if (v == "imgA") {
        target.className = "html";
    } else if (v == "imgB") {
        target.className = "oracle";
    } else if (v == "imgC") {
        target.className = "linux";
    } else if (v == "imgD") {
        target.className = "php";
    } else if (v == "imgE") {
        target.className = "java";
    } else if (v == "imgF") {
        target.className = "prod";
    } else if (v == "imgG") {
        target.className = "pm";
    } else if (v == "imgH") {
        target.className = "design";
    } else {
        target.className = "chart";
    }
}
function changeReset() {
    var target = document.getElementById("target");
    target.className = "";
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <a id="imgA" onmouseover="change('imgA');" onmouseout="changeReset();" href="#"><img src="theme/images/Albania.png" alt="" /></a>
        <a id="imgB" onmouseover="change('imgB');" onmouseout="changeReset();" href="#"><img src="theme/images/Algeria.png" alt="" /></a>
        <a id="imgC" onmouseover="change('imgC');" onmouseout="changeReset();" href="#"><img src="theme/images/Brazil.png" alt="" /></a>
        <a id="imgD" onmouseover="change('imgD');" onmouseout="changeReset();" href="#"><img src="theme/images/Brunei.png" alt="" /></a>
        <a id="imgE" onmouseover="change('imgE');" onmouseout="changeReset();" href="#"><img src="theme/images/Chad.png" alt="" /></a>
        <a id="imgF" onmouseover="change('imgF');" onmouseout="changeReset();" href="#"><img src="theme/images/Chad.png" alt="" /></a>
        <a id="imgG" onmouseover="change('imgG');" onmouseout="changeReset();" href="#"><img src="theme/images/Chad.png" alt="" /></a>
        <a id="imgH" onmouseover="change('imgH');" onmouseout="changeReset();" href="#"><img src="theme/images/Chad.png" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="target"></div></body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have to deal with is pretty gross.  If this page is going to require ongoing maintenance or if you just want to sleep better at night consider using unobtrusive javascript and a nice DOM manipulation library like JQuery to clean this up [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/aXsKP/1/).  If I understand your question I believe all you need to do is change:

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

to have the chart class on it by default:

```
<div id="target" class="chart"></div>
```

Comment: thanks RSG, this solved the issue partically.  When the page loads, the chart now displays, but once I hover over a thumbnail then remove that cursor from the thumbnail, the default image never returns.  Do you know how this can be resolved?  I agree I need to switch over to jquery, when I have more time.

Comment: I figured it out, but you lead me in the right direction, thank you for everything.